# (Gnu) sed command to change a matching part of a line

Tags: sed

Is there a way in (Gnu) `sed` to replace all characters in a matching part of a string? For example I might have a list of file paths with several (arbitrary number of) paths in each line, e.g.:

```
/a/b/c/d/e /f/g/XXX/h/i /j/k/l/m
/n/o/p /q/r/s/t/u /v/x/x/y
/z/XXX/a/b /c/d/e/f
```

I would like to replace all the slashes in paths containing *XXX* keping all the others untouched, e.g.:

```
/a/b/c/d/e #f#g#XXX#h#i /j/k/l/m
/n/o/p /q/r/s/t/u /v/x/x/y
#z#XXX#a#b /c/d/e/f
```

Unfortunately I cannot come up with a solution. Maybe it's even impossible with `sed`. But I'm curious if somebody find a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can replace any `/` preceding `XXX` with no intervening spaces like this:

```
# Using extended regex syntax
s!/([^ ]*XXX)!#\1!
```

It's a very similar substitution for those that follow `XXX`.

Putting them together in a loop makes this program:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf

:loop
s!/([^ ]*XXX)!#\1!
s!(XXX[^ ]*)/!\1#!
tloop
```

Output:

```
/a/b/c/d/e #f#g#XXX#h#i /j/k/l/m
/n/o/p /q/r/s/t/u /v/x/x/y
#z#XXX#a#b /c/d/e/f
```

---

That said, it might be simpler to use a pipeline, to break the file paths into individual lines and then reassemble them after the substitution:

```sh
sed -e 's/ *$//;s/  */&\n/g' \
  | sed -e '/XXX/y,/,#,' \
  | sed -e ':a;/ $/{N;s/\n//;ba}'
```

Comment: These are interesting solutions that work for me that way. Thank you.